# How to round the edge of donut chart in kendo UI using angular2

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I want the donut chart with round edge as shown in the picture, need help

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported out of the box. However, you can use the series **[visual property](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.visual)** to add rounded end caps to the segments.

## **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/OwuPix)**

The visual function gives you the start and end angles of the segment as well as the inner and outer radius, and the coordinates of the center. Given these, you can use trigonometry to get from polar (angle and radius) to Cartesian (x and y) coordinates in order to draw the circles at the start of each segment. For the last segment you also need to draw a circle at the end in the color of the first segment to make it look right.

`e.createVisual()` gets the original segment.

```
 visual: function (e) {
    var seg = e.createVisual(); //get original segment geometry
   
    var circRad = (e.radius - e.innerRadius) /2; //end cap radius
    var dist = e.innerRadius + circRad; 
    var spoint = polarToCartesian(e.center.x, e.center.y, dist, e.startAngle);
    var epoint = polarToCartesian(e.center.x, e.center.y, dist, e.endAngle);

    //draw circle at start of segment
    var startArcGeometry = new kendo.geometry.Arc([spoint.x, spoint.y], {
      startAngle: 0,endAngle: 360,radiusX: circRad,radiusY: circRad         
    });                      
    var startArc = new kendo.drawing.Arc(startArcGeometry, {
      fill: {color: e.options.color},
      stroke: {color: "none"}
    });
  
    var group = new kendo.drawing.Group();
    group.append(seg, startArc);

    //for last item draw circle at end of segment in color of first item
    var lastItem = e.series.data[e.series.data.length - 1];
    if (lastItem.category == e.category){                        
      var firstItem = e.series.data[0];
      console.log(firstItem.color);

      var endArcGeometry = new kendo.geometry.Arc([epoint.x, epoint.y], {
        startAngle: 0,endAngle: 360,radiusX: circRad, radiusY: circRad  
      });

      var endArc = new kendo.drawing.Arc(endArcGeometry, {
        fill: {color: firstItem.color},
        stroke: {color: "none" }
      });

      group.append(endArc);
   }      
   return group;
 }
```

Polar to Cartesian conversion:

```
function polarToCartesian(centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) {
    var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees) * Math.PI / 180.0;

    return {
      x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
      y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
    };
}
```

Comment: tried this ..i'm getting an error saying 'not able to find name kendo' Since i'm trying this in angular 2, can u suggest how to use geometry.arc & drawing.arc methods in angular 2.

Comment: @Sukesh if you are loading kendo.all.min.js on your page, lendo.drawing and kendo.geometry should be available...